# xslt copy deep xml if exists if not create

Tags: xslt-1.0

```
<root>   
 <xnode>
    <Node1/>
    <Node2/>
    <Node3> 
       <CNode1>
         <CCNode1>
            <CCField1>
            <CCField2>
               <CCCNode1/>
          </CCNode1>
         <CCNode2>
            <CCCNode3/>
     </Node3>

      <Node4/>
</xnode>
 <xnode>
    <Node1/>
    <Node2/>
    <Node3> 
       <CNode1>
           <CCNode2>
            <CCCNode3/>
     </Node3>
      <Node4/>
   </xnode>
  <xnode>
    <Node1/>
    <Node2/>
    <Node3> 
       <CNode1>
         <CCNode1>
            <CCField1>
            <CCField2>
               <CCCNode1/>
          </CCNode1>
         <CCNode2>
            <CCCNode3/>
      </Node3>
      <Node4/>
   </xnode>
 </root>
```

In the above xml, I need to copy all the nodes and values except for Node3 - CNode1 - CCNode1. i.e. if CCNode1 exists copy as its including the child elements, if not, create CCNode1 with the corresponding fields and child elements. For ex, here the first and third xnode has CCNode1 whereas its missing in the second xnode. So copy the first and 3rd node1 as it is and create the CCNode1 and its child elements in the 2nd xnode with some dummy values.

Please suggest how to achieve this with XSLT.

THanks

Comment: Your XML example is not well formed.  For example, your Node3 tag is not closed.  So, I suggest fixing up your input XML and providing output XML.

Comment: Sorry, missed it while editing, updated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the best I can tell is that you need an identity template to copy everything.  And, then you need a template like the following to select Node3/CNode1 nodes that do not have a CCNode1 node.  There you can add your nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="Node3/CNode1[not(.//CCNode1)]">
  <xsl:copy>

     Add your ccNode1 and child nodes here.

     <!-- Output other child nodes of CNode1  -->
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Identity. -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but I was thinking if I could alter my implementation. Is it possible to remove the whole xnode (with all child nodes) if CCNode1 doesn't or exists with CCField1 value 0 but copy the rest of the file as it is?

Comment: Just add a template to select xnode's that meet you conditions.  Then don't do anything inside the template.  This will suppress.  ie.  <xsl:template match="xnode[not(.//CCNode1) or .//CCField1='0' "/>  You can play with the XPath to meet your needs.

Comment: I tried it already, but its still copying the parent nodes, which I don't need. i.e. <xnode>     <Node1/>     <Node2/>  are still getting copied. I need the whole xnode and subnodes to be not copied. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: tsjo,  Can you post your code?  Also, please fix your XML so that every tag has a closing tag.  Thanks.